# Loop cut not working on my blender project?

Tags: modeling, project

friends, I'm confused with my problem. is there anyone who can fix my project?
I want to do vertical edge like in a photo.

my project:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vgpIo6qGXz5TJQUaBbO2Pn6IEMUJxGot
[image: This is what I want.]

[image: This is mine. I cant make vertical edge]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question, but a request to do work for you.

Comment: no, I want help. I don't mean anything bad. I just want a solution.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do and with what you have problem.

Comment: I don't mean that it is bad or that I am voting to close the post because of some evil plan of yours, it is just not the right place for it. This is a question an answer site. Yours is a request, not a question.

Comment: I saw someone like me asking for help. then I saw him share his project.. And I thought it was normal, I tried to ask for help like him.

Comment: Define your problem clearly in form of a question. Clearly state what your desired result is, tell us why you are trying to atchieve it, what you have tried as far, what results you got and how they were different from your expectations. Add pictures where apropriate, sharing a .blend file also helps, but still describe everything in words and in form of a question. If you do all of the above, I am sure you will get good answers to your question quickly.

Comment: okay, I got it. I'm sorry to Bother You. I'm new, you know :)

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to see your object by transparency, you'll see an inner face, you can't create any vertical edge loop because of this inner face: with this kind of topology Blender can't guess what face the edge is supposed to go through. So just select and delete it.

[image]

Comment: is there anything that might fix?

Comment: yes, if your press Z you'll see these vertices by transparency, just select and delete them, then again try your ctrl R to create your vertical edge loop, it will work